# "cat washes its face" using two words?

Tags: phrases

Is it possible to say "cat washes its face" in English using two words only? I.e. "cat + (verb)"?

Such construct is possible in Russian ("кот умывается"), which has verb (well, a variation of a verb) that normally means "wash face", and "self" can be replaced with suffix. Is there a similar verb or some kind of compact (two words, including "cat") idiom in English for that? It has been bugging me for a long time...

P.S. Slang is also okay, as long as it isn't too obscure.

--EDIT--

Detailed info:

The "cat" part *is* important - I'm interested in two-word idiom that *precisely* refers to "washing face with front paw" behavior performed by **cats**. The "cat" word doesn't have to be present as long as idiom/sentence/phrase is compact enough and refers precisely to this kind of action. Perhaps something similar to "making biscuits". Although Russian verb "умывать(ся)" is applicable to people, I'm not looking for general verb (that is applicable to everything) meaning "wash one's face" - I'm only interested in cat-specific verb or sentence that is normally associated with this particular cat behavior.

Russian "кот умывается" in most situations refers to a cat washing face with front paw (can be used in jokingly manner to describe cat playing with water dripping from faucet, though, but that's irrelevant). English "the cat is washing itself" is very specific about time/continuity, but is less specific about exact action and can be used to describe cat that is cleaning its tail, for example - in other words, compared to "кот умывается" it is not strictly associated with cat's "wash face with front paw" action.

Comment: I hope so, considering we have [catnap](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catnap).

Comment: I see from your comments to my answer that your primary question is about a single-word idiom for "washing one's face", and not an idiom for washing oneself in general. Is this correct? Also, it's not the cat part that matters?

Comment: @MarkBeadles: "Also, it's not the cat part that matters?" No, that's not correct. I was interested in two-word idiom that *precisely* refers to "washing face with front paw" behavior performed by **cats**. As I said - perhaps, something like to "making biscuits". Russian verb "умывать(ся)" is applicable to people, but I wasn't looking for general verb (that is applicable to everything) meaning "wash one's face"  - I'm only interested in cat-specific verb or a commonly used sentence that is normally associated with this particular cat behavior.

Comment: I take it that the important thing here is that the cat, in washing its face, must lick its paw first, unlike the rest of its body,which it can clean more  directly. Is that correct?

Comment: @JeffSahol: "Is that correct?" The important part is that it washes face [*using its paw*](http://dwpicture.com.au/photos/34929b.jpg). Whether it actually licks it before or after isn't really important.

Comment: Upon your edit reflecting the exactitude with which you are seeking, I've removed my answer as it was more general and didn't refer only to a cat grooming its face by licking its paw.

Comment: @MarkBeadles: That's a pity. Even if it wasn't exact answer, it was still quite useful/informative.

Comment: If you think it was still useful, then I will undelete it. Thanks.

Comment: Don't expect that what is possible with Russian verbs is possible in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edited*:

I think you are asking if there is a single-word idiom in English for "**washing one's face**".

I have never heard such an idiom. We nearly always say "**wash one's face**" and don't have a single word for this in English.

If you're not limited to "face", then there are other idioms one could use: *the cat is bathing*, *the cat is washing itself*, *the cat is cleaning itself*.

*Note: I misunderstood the question originally and I gave an answer about "washing oneself as a cat might do". That answer is below:*

---

You could say something like "(the) cat self-washes" or "(the) cat self-cleans".

The [prefix **self-**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/self-#Prefix_2) is a little bit (a very little bit) like the Russian suffix **-ся**. But it's not grammaticalized; it's more of a lexically transparent bit added on to the verb.

This is a bit problematic for a couple reasons though:

1. English has articles and they are usually required. Russian doesn't have articles as such, but in English we have to say "**The** cat washes" or "**A** cat washes".
2. The English simple present tense is not used to refer to events that are currently happening. Crazy, I know. Instead we use the present progressive construction: `be + verb +  -ing`. So instead of "The cat washes itself" we say "The cat **is washing** itself."

So the normal English way to express the same idea as "кот умывается" would be "The cat is washing itself" with 5 words, not 2.

Comment: "English has articles" I think it'll be fair enough to exclude particles from total word count. "The cat is washing itself" One of the other reasons why I asked the question is because this particular sentence has slightly different meaning. If you copy-paste "кот умывается" into google image search, you instantly get picture of cat holding paw against face or washing face. However "cat is washing itself" returns you image of a cat that licks its hind leg in 2nd hit. Because in english cat can "make muffins", I suppose there should be also some other idiom (I'm not aware of) for face-washing.

Comment: Although the present tense is used to refer to event that are currently happening when using the "documentary style of narration: "While I remain safely in the jeep, the lioness stretches lazily as Jim approaches from behind."

Answer (score 7):

> cat preening

I just searched 'cat preening' and get mostly the kind of image you are describing (cat washing its face with paw).

Ok, so the third hit is cat cleaning the top of its tail. But all the rest are face washing. Including cat woman.

Preening by itself would first apply to a bird cleaning itself, but also applies to cats.
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/preen

Answer (score 3):

Cats are said to *groom* themselves. When you search for "cat grooming itself" you get lots of [photos of cats licking their paws to clean their face.](http://www.google.com/search?q=cat+grooming+itself&hl=en&gbv=2&um=1&tbm=isch&tab=wi&gs_l=img.3..0l10.28077.28077.0.28490.1.1.0.0.0.0.238.238.2-1.1.0...0.0.RyeoEPdHzCA&oq=cat+grooming+itself&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=) That's what I think of when I think of a cat grooming itself, even though *grooming* is not exclusive to the face.

Comment: NB your search is actually for "cat grooming itself". If you search for ["cat grooming"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cat+grooming%22&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&biw=1280&bih=675&sei=YXPFT7biDKnb6gHYgPmcBg) you get mostly pictures of people grooming their cats.

Comment: @MarkBeadles. Oops...thanks; I corrected it. By the way, I have never heard of a cat *preening* itself.

Answer (score -1):

I have sometimes heard this behaviour referred to as a "tongue bath", which might do the trick, as the behaviour is sufficiently specific to cats that people are likely to know what you mean.  If you wanted to make it into a verb "tongue bathing" would probably work.

Comment: A google search for "tongue bathing" will return many results. To my eternal regret, very few of them involve cats grooming themselves.